# scrollbar siempre comienza en la parte superior

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

La idea es hacer que cuando la pagina web se cargue siempre este en el top de la pagina, por alguna razón depende del navegador sale desplazado un poco hacia abajo. solo estoy usando bootstrap 4, he probado varias veces cambiado el CSS poniendo el `margin top 0px`, pero no funciona, pensé de alguna manera hacerlo con JS pero no se si es posible..

Comment: Deberias incluir tu codigo, de otro modo es imposible ayudarte.

Comment: talves con este JS te pueda funcionar (function(){window.scrollTo(0, 0);})